# BIML with ScriptComponent Produces Package but won't open in SSDT

Tags: biml

UPDATE:  Modified post to include the simplest solution possible to reproduce the issue.

I am struggling with using the ScriptComponentProject in BIML.  I am Using VS 2017 and BIML Express 2018 latest version.

I am trying to create a script component that will retrieve an error description and the offending column name using the strategy laid out in this [blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2149/capturing-and-logging-data-load-errors-for-an-ssis-package/).

Not many BIML examples out there for script component but my solution is a mix of following [Varigence Doc](https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Samples/Biml/Script+Component+Project)  & [a blog from Joost](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2015/02/creating-biml-script-component.html).

When I compile the BIML it creates the package without error; however, when I open the package I receive the error message:

> "Value Does not fall withing the expected range"

Below is a stripped down version of the code which is bare minimum to reproduce the error.  Should be as simple as copying the code into a .biml file and generating the SSIS package.   The sample reads from a one column CSV file, converts the column in the source to an integer.  Data conversion errors are directed to the script component which then adds the offending column and error description columns to the output buffer, this output is then written to a flat file destination.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <FlatFileConnection Name="Errors" FilePath="C:\Users\username\Desktop\BasicSSISErrors.csv" FileFormat="Errors" />
        <FlatFileConnection Name="Source" FilePath="C:\Users\username\Desktop\BasicSSIS.csv" FileFormat="Source" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="PackageFromBIML" Language="None" ConstraintMode="LinearOnCompletion" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="Data Flow Task">
                    <Transformations>
                        <FlatFileSource Name="Flat File Source" LocaleId="None" FileNameColumnName="" ConnectionName="Source" />
                        <DataConversion Name="Data Conversion">
                            <DataflowOverrides>
                                <OutputPath OutputPathName="Output">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <Column ErrorRowDisposition="RedirectRow" TruncationRowDisposition="RedirectRow" ColumnName="Converted" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </OutputPath>
                            </DataflowOverrides>
                            <Columns>
                                <Column SourceColumn="Integers" TargetColumn="Converted" DataType="SByte" />
                            </Columns>
                        </DataConversion>
                        <ScriptComponentTransformation Name="Script Component" ProjectCoreName="SC_a8f35334a2234702a5f92abdcbedb4e4">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="Data Conversion.Error" />
                            <ScriptComponentProjectReference ScriptComponentProjectName="SC_a8f35334a2234702a5f92abdcbedb4e4" />
                        </ScriptComponentTransformation>
                        <FlatFileDestination Name="Flat File Destination" LocaleId="None" ConnectionName="Errors">
                            <Header></Header>
                        </FlatFileDestination>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
    <FileFormats>
        <FlatFileFormat Name="Errors" CodePage="1252" TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="true" RowDelimiter="">
            <Columns>
                <Column Name="Integers" Length="50" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="Comma" MaximumWidth="50" />
                <Column Name="ErrorCode" Delimiter="Comma" />
                <Column Name="ErrorColumn" Delimiter="Comma" />
                <Column Name="ErrorColumnName" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="Comma" />
                <Column Name="ErrorDescription" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="CRLF" />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
        <FlatFileFormat Name="Source" CodePage="1252" TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="true" RowDelimiter="">
            <Columns>
                <Column Name="Integers" Length="50" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="CRLF" MaximumWidth="50" />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
    </FileFormats>
    <ScriptProjects>
        <ScriptComponentProject Name="SC_a8f35334a2234702a5f92abdcbedb4e4" ProjectCoreName="SC_a8f35334a2234702a5f92abdcbedb4e4.csproj">
            <OutputBuffers>
                <OutputBuffer Name="Output 0">
                    <Columns>
                        <Column Name="ErrorColumnName" Length="500" DataType="AnsiString" CodePage="1252" />
                        <Column Name="ErrorDescription" Length="500" DataType="AnsiString" CodePage="1252" />
                    </Columns>
                </OutputBuffer>
            </OutputBuffers>
            <InputBuffer Name="Input 0">
                <Columns>
                    <Column Name="ErrorCode" />
                    <Column Name="ErrorColumn" />
                </Columns>
            </InputBuffer>
            <AssemblyReferences>
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.AddIn.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml.dll" />
            </AssemblyReferences>
                        <Files>
       <!-- Left alignment of .Net script to get a neat layout in package-->
            <File Path="AssemblyInfo.cs">
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("SC_a8f35334a2234702a5f92abdcbedb4e4.csproj")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("SC_a8f35334a2234702a5f92abdcbedb4e4.csproj")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
                           </File>

                           <File Path="main.cs">
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
  public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        Row.ErrorDescription = this.ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.ErrorCode);
        IDTSComponentMetaData130 componentMetaData = this.ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
        Row.ErrorColumnName = componentMetaData.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn);
    }
}
                </File>
            </Files>
        </ScriptComponentProject>
    </ScriptProjects>
</Biml>
```

Comment: Mobile at the moment, but with the ability to reverse engineer packages now freely available in Biml express, I'd create a tiny sample package, reverse engineer that one and compare the generated Biml script component to the one you've built

Comment: @billinkc - Tried using the convert package to BIML,  the resulting BIML does not include the actual code part i.e. There is not a <Files> element.   The BIML that is produced is for the most part the same as what I have.

Comment: I updated this post to include the simplest solution possible to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by switching the SSIS Project Properties to target SQL Server 2016, it was defaulted to targeting SQL Server 2017.

This appears to be a bug within the Varigence product, as this [forum post](https://varigence.com/Forums?threadID=9832) confirms others are experiencing the issue.  No updates from Varigence other than "send us a repo" back in February 2019.   Varigence states there is a "preview build" which fixes the issue but the preview build is not linked to and follow up posts in the thread which request the preview build have gone unanswered.  I'm guessing [this is the preview build](https://varigence.com/products/preview).  I tried the 2019 preview and it did not fix the issue.  The post from Scott Currie mentioning what the preview build fixes doesn't match up with my situation, he states the problem occurs when you are downlevel platform targeting i.e. using VS 2017 to target SQL 2016.  I was not doing this, I was using VS2017 to target SQL 2017.

I also fought another issue after this where I was receiving the error:

> Cannot create user component make sure there is at least one class
>   marked with SsisScriptTaskEntryPointattribute

I corrected this by adding an assembly reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll.  This assembly reference is not included in Varigence examples.

Full corrected solution is as follows:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <FlatFileConnection Name="Errors" FilePath="C:\Users\username\Desktop\BasicSSISErrors.csv" FileFormat="Errors" />
        <FlatFileConnection Name="Source" FilePath="C:\Users\username\Desktop\BasicSSIS.csv" FileFormat="Source" />
    </Connections>
    <ScriptProjects>
        <ScriptComponentProject ScriptLanguage="CSharp"  Name="SCR - ErrorHelper" ProjectCoreName="SC_a8f35334a2234702a5f92abdcbedb4e4">
            <AssemblyReferences>
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.dll" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data.dll" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml.dll" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Core.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.AddIn.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data.dll" />
                   <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml.dll" />
            </AssemblyReferences>
                        <Files>
       <!-- Left alignment of .Net script to get a neat layout in package-->
            <File Path="AssemblyInfo.cs">
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("SC_2bca370105ff4883a705860bac68cfba.csproj")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Varigence")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("SC_2bca370105ff4883a705860bac68cfba.csproj")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright @ Varigence 2011")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]


[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]</File>
        <File Path="main.cs">
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
  public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        Row.ErrorDescription = this.ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.ErrorCode);

        var componentMetaData130 = this.ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
        if (componentMetaData130 != null)
        {
            // 0 means no specific column is identified by ErrorColumn, this time.
            if (Row.ErrorColumn == 0)
            {
                Row.ErrorColumnName = "Check the row for a violation of a foreign key constraint. No specific column is identified by ErrorColum";
            }
            else
            {
                Row.ErrorColumnName = componentMetaData130.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn);
            }
        }
    }
}
                </File>
            </Files>
        <OutputBuffers>
                <OutputBuffer Name="Output0">
                    <Columns>
                        <Column Name="ErrorColumnName" Length="500" DataType="AnsiString" CodePage="1252" />
                        <Column Name="ErrorDescription" Length="500" DataType="AnsiString" CodePage="1252" />
                    </Columns>
                </OutputBuffer>
            </OutputBuffers>
            <InputBuffer Name="Input0">
                <Columns>
                    <Column Name="ErrorCode" />
                    <Column Name="ErrorColumn" />
                </Columns>
            </InputBuffer>
        </ScriptComponentProject>
    </ScriptProjects>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="PackageFromBIML" Language="None" ConstraintMode="LinearOnCompletion" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="Data Flow Task">
                    <Transformations>
                        <FlatFileSource Name="Flat File Source" LocaleId="None" FileNameColumnName="" ConnectionName="Source" />
                        <DataConversion Name="Data Conversion">
                            <DataflowOverrides>
                                <OutputPath OutputPathName="Output">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <Column ErrorRowDisposition="RedirectRow" TruncationRowDisposition="RedirectRow" ColumnName="Converted" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </OutputPath>
                            </DataflowOverrides>
                            <Columns>
                                <Column SourceColumn="Integers" TargetColumn="Converted" DataType="SByte" />
                            </Columns>
                        </DataConversion>
                        <ScriptComponentTransformation Name="Script Component" ProjectCoreName="SC_a8f35334a2234702a5f92abdcbedb4e4">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="Data Conversion.Error" />
                            <ScriptComponentProjectReference ScriptComponentProjectName="SCR - ErrorHelper" />
                        </ScriptComponentTransformation>
                        <FlatFileDestination Name="Flat File Destination" LocaleId="None" ConnectionName="Errors">
                            <Header></Header>
                        </FlatFileDestination>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
    <FileFormats>
        <FlatFileFormat Name="Errors" CodePage="1252" TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="true" RowDelimiter="">
            <Columns>
                <Column Name="Integers" Length="50" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="Comma" MaximumWidth="50" />
                <Column Name="ErrorCode" Delimiter="Comma" />
                <Column Name="ErrorColumn" Delimiter="Comma" />
                <Column Name="ErrorColumnName" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="Comma" />
                <Column Name="ErrorDescription" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="CRLF" />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
        <FlatFileFormat Name="Source" CodePage="1252" TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="true" RowDelimiter="">
            <Columns>
                <Column Name="Integers" Length="50" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="CRLF" MaximumWidth="50" />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
    </FileFormats>

</Biml>
```

Comment: Update:  Varigence reached out to me and informed me that this issue has been fixed in a new release due out some time in the week of 5/19/2019.